# matrix of numbers to matrix of dates

Tags: r

i have a dataframe containing column of dates, but some days are missing - `"2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08"` - (6th and 7th are missing). Its daily dollar rate dataframe.
Also i got matrix cpt_vecs
matrix

```
structure(c(0, 216, 216, 407, 623, 764, 0, 216, 448, 464, 607, 
764, 0, 143, 448, 464, 541, 764, 0, 216, 448, 448, 541, 764), .Dim = c(6L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("var_1", "var_2", "var_3", "var_4"
)))
```

[image: matrix with values]

If i use `data_test$day[cpt_vecs]` I get vector of dates

```
structure(c(13823, 13823, 14098, 14410, 14608, 13823, 14155, 
14179, 14386, 14608, 13720, 14155, 14179, 14291, 14608, 13823, 
14155, 14155, 14291, 14608), class = "Date")
```

and after using `matrix(data_test$day[cpt_vecs], nrow = nrow(cpt_vecs), ncol = ncol(cpt_vecs))` i get

```
structure(c(13823, 13823, 14098, 14410, 14608, 13823, 14155, 
14179, 14386, 14608, 13720, 14155, 14179, 14291, 14608, 13823, 
14155, 14155, 14291, 14608, 13823, 13823, 14098, 14410), .Dim = c(6L, 
4L))
```

I need to change that matrix into matrix of dates (so for example 216 from that matrix transforms into `2007-11-06` which is `data_frame$day[216]`)

Comment: In the future, please use `dput(your_data)` to include your data in the question. Paste the results from your R console into the question.

Comment: You did not include the values of  `data_test$day` in your question and `cpt_vecs` is a matrix with more than 2 columns so it is not appropriate inside square brackets []. It is not possible to put a date object into a matrix. You can store the numbers or the character strings. You can easily convert those to dates when you use them however. If you want to store them as dates, you will have to use a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem. I'm assuming that your data is this:

```
dta.vec <- structure(c(13823, 13823, 14098, 14410, 14608, 13823, 14155, 
14179, 14386, 14608, 13720, 14155, 14179, 14291, 14608, 13823, 
14155, 14155, 14291, 14608), class = "Date")
str(dta.vec)
#  Date[1:20], format: "2007-11-06" "2007-11-06" "2008-08-07" "2009-06-15" "2009-12-30
# "2007-11-06" "2008-10-03" "2008-10-27" "2009-05-22" "2009-12-30" ...
```

Now split the vector into 4 lists that will be the four columns of the data frame:

```
dta.lst <- split(datvec, rep(1:4, each=5))
```

Finally, combine the columns into a data frame.

```
dta.df <- do.call(data.frame, dta.lst)
dta.df
#           X1         X2         X3         X4
# 1 2007-11-06 2007-11-06 2007-07-26 2007-11-06
# 2 2007-11-06 2008-10-03 2008-10-03 2008-10-03
# 3 2008-08-07 2008-10-27 2008-10-27 2008-10-03
# 4 2009-06-15 2009-05-22 2009-02-16 2009-02-16
# 5 2009-12-30 2009-12-30 2009-12-30 2009-12-30
str(dta.df)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ X1: Date, format: "2007-11-06" "2007-11-06" "2008-08-07" "2009-06-15" ...
#  $ X2: Date, format: "2007-11-06" "2008-10-03" "2008-10-27" "2009-05-22" ...
#  $ X3: Date, format: "2007-07-26" "2008-10-03" "2008-10-27" "2009-02-16" ...
#  $ X4: Date, format: "2007-11-06" "2008-10-03" "2008-10-03" "2009-02-16" ...
```